# Returning to original view of tab bar controller within code when that selectedIndex is already selected

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a tab bar controller with the first view (index 0) having a segue to another view (*but stays on index 0 of the tab bar*). In this segued view, I have a "Back" button which I want to return to the original view at index 0 when selected. However, when I use:

self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

I remain on the current segued view. I know it should work because if I change the index to 1 or 2 then it switches to the other views.
Also, from the segued view, if I click on the tab bar icon for index 0 (which is the one already highlighted/selected) *it does exactly what I want and brings me back to the original view from the segued view*. So how do I get my button to do exactly what the tab bar does when I select the already highlighted/selected index?

Update:
To simplify, when clicking one of the tab bar icons, what is that action doing in code since I need to add the same exact code to a button.

Update2:
I was able to figure it out.
I used the following instead:
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used

self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

instead of

self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0